# Why can't I access Open Hardware Monitor's web server from any other device?

Tags: display, web, windows-firewall, open

I am trying to set up Open Hardware Monitor's web server and am running into an issue.

I can't access the webpage on any other machines on my local network. I am hoping you all might be able to help me out.

Information:

- Win 8.1 x64
- Open Hardware Monitor version 0.7.1 Beta (The default download on their site)

Steps Taken:

- Installed OHM
- Started web server
- Set an exception for executable in Windows firewall
- Set an exception for port in Windows firewall (all types of traffic)
- I have confirmed the port number I am trying to access it from

Symptoms:

- On the local machine I can view the server at 192.169.xx.xx:port (I am not using 127.0.0.1)
- On remote machines, attempts to access this address time out.

Any suggestions?

(Edited for clarity regarding IP address with regard to Breakthrough's comment.)

Comment: Do you have Wireshark installed by any chance?  It might be worth running to see if the requests are even getting to the computer, otherwise the issue might lie in your router configuration.

Comment: I do not, though I am somewhat familiar with it. If you were interested in giving me a quick rundown of the steps required I'd be happy to try it.

Comment: I haven't used it in a while myself, but [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/) might help.  Wireshark captures the packets your NIC receives.  Close all programs except your server, start Wireshark, and try to make a request from another machine.  You should see some packets received on the server from the IP address of the computer you made the request from (e.g. pay attention to packets where the `Source` is the IP address of the computer making the request) - if not, I would start looking into your router configuration.

Comment: Ok, I think I have done this. I opened wireshark and set the filter to 'ip.addr == xx.xx.xx.xx' (where xx is the IP of the secondary machine). I then tried to access the ip address and port of the server. No traffic appeared wireshark. If I did the filtering right, what should I look for in my router to see if it is blocking that traffic?

Comment: Try capturing packets *without* any filtering, and then applying the filter after you've left Wireshark running on the server for a bit and made a few attempts to access the server (or just have a look through the packets yourself, closing any other programs to avoid unnecessary traffic from showing up).  If that doesn't yield any results, well, admittedly, I'm not too familiar with networking myself, so I might not be the best help with that aspect; however, I would double-check that you setup your subnet masks properly, and gateway address.

Comment: I captured a steady stream, but with no programs open I still am seeing traffic. (I think largely from other computers on the network.) I couldn't see anything in that view that seemed to be from the secondary computer. Edit: I'll look at the router, thank you for your help!